# Prove or disprove these two statements.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

1. If $f(x)$ is differentiable for every $x$, then $f(x^2)$ is continuous for every x.
2. If $f(x)$ is differentiable and not negative, then $\sqrt {f(x)}$ is differentiable. 
   My Work:

1. Intuition just drived me to think this is right so I tried to prove. $f(x)$ is differentiable for all $x$ then it's continuous for all $x$, is it just a matter of substituting $x^2$ and that's it? or I'm missing something?
2. I got this one wrong (it's a false statement), I can't still think of a function that counters it.
   It would mean alot to me if you show me your thought process from when you face these type of questions, since they're my weakness and I most of the time just follow intuition and don't have any idea where to start.

   Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

For the first you should use that the composition of continuous functions is continuous to conclude the exercise.

For the second note that $x^2$ is a counterexample, as $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$ which is clearly non differentiable.

Comment: For the second one $x$ itself, defined on the non-negative reals, would do.